# ASP.NET Core JWT Authorization Attribute Not Triggering for Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core web application and implementing JWT authorization using a custom attribute [JwtAuthorize]. The goal is to ensure that specific controller actions are protected and require a valid JWT token for access. However, I'm encountering an issue where the [JwtAuthorize] attribute is not triggering for the controller actions where I've applied it.

Here's the setup I have:

I created a custom JwtAuthorizeAttribute class that extends AuthorizeAttribute and implements IAsyncAuthorizationFilter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class JwtAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool ApplyAuthorization { get; set; } = false;

    public JwtAuthorizeAttribute(bool applyAuthorization = false)
    {
        ApplyAuthorization = applyAuthorization;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

        if (ApplyAuthorization)
        {

            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var token = httpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

                if (jwtToken.ValidTo > DateTime.UtcNow) // Check token expiration
                {
                    httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Redirect to login or handle expired token
                    context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Redirect to login or handle unauthorized access
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs, I registered the JwtAuthorizeAttribute as a scoped service:

```
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddScoped<AuthService>();
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddScoped<JwtAuthorizeAttribute>();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["AppSettings:ValidIssuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["AppSettings:ValidAudience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["AppSettings:Secret"]))
        };
    });
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    });

    services.AddMvcCore(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(JwtAuthorizeAttribute)); 
    });
```

I added the [JwtAuthorize] attribute to a specific controller action that I want to protect:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
            return View();
    }

    [JwtAuthorize(ApplyAuthorization = true)] // Apply authorization
    public IActionResult Dashboard ()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The problem is that when I access the Dashboard action, the [JwtAuthorize] attribute does not seem to be triggering and it returns 401 response immediately. I verified this by placing breakpoints within the OnAuthorizationAsync method of the JwtAuthorizeAttribute class, but the breakpoints are not hit when accessing the Dashboard action.

I have double-checked that the JWT token is valid and stored correctly in the session. Additionally, I noticed that the [JwtAuthorize] attribute works as expected for other actions where I didn't explicitly apply the attribute.

My question is: Why is the [JwtAuthorize] attribute not triggering for the Dashboard action, even though it is being triggered for other actions?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you pls check [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)?  I'm also confused why you want to have custom authorize attribute......

Comment: I am trying to implement an authorization system. What i am trying to do is to authorize to my .net project with a simple JWT. I have found a workaround i have enabled the authorization for all of my routes and in JwtAuthorization attribute i whitelisted the routes that doesn't need authorization. So it is fixed right now but if there is a better and efficient method to achieve this i can also try it

Comment: Hi, the controllers which we didn't add the `[Authorize]` attribute should be allowed to access anomyous, if the controller had the `[Authorize]` attribute, we could also add `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in specific action method.